# "At the back of the restaurant" or "in the back of the restaurant"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I see both on Google Books.

Which is the correct option?

Example sentence:

> Mary and I picked a table at/in the back of the restaurant.

Comment: They're both correct, and essentially identical in meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you eat *at* the restaurant or *in* the restaurant? Both are correct, the difference is whether you picture yourself at a location or inside a building.

In the same way, do you see yourselves *at* the back of a location, or *inside* the building, near the back?  Both are fine.

You can also say "by the back", "toward the back", "near the back", and various others.  Each has slightly different nuance.

> The restrooms are down that aisle, toward the back of the store.
>
> The restrooms are by/near the back of the store, next to the loading dock.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a distinct difference in the two.  Here's how I would interpret each:

> We ate the back of the restaurant.

Expresses you chose a table on the regular dining floor at the opposite end of the room from the door.

> We ate in the back of the restaurant.

Expresses you ate probably in a separate room located behind the regular dining floor.  'In' suggesting you were in a different enclosed space.  You would also direct a delivery person to put an item 'in the back', presumable where the storeroom is located.